# python linkedlist partly reverse

Tags: python, list, linked-list, reverse

I got a linked list in class like

```
7,5,3,1,2,4,6,8
```

I want to get the output like

```
1,3,5,7,2,4,6,8
```

when I try to use reverse code below:

```
class Linkedlist:
def __init__(self, L = None):
...
def partlyreverse(self):
    tail = self.head
    current_node = self.head.next_node
    tail.next_node = None
    while current_node.value % 2 == 1:
        next_current_node = current_node.next_node
        current_node.next_node = tail
        tail = current_node
        current_node = next_current_node

    self.head = tail
L = Linkedlist([7,5,3,1,2,4,6,8])
L.partlyreverse()
```

I can only get

```
1,3,5,7
```

so how could I do this?

Thanks!

Comment: try storing all the values in a collection and do:
`sorted([odd for odd in list1 if odd % 2 != 0 ]) + sorted([even for even in list1 if even % 2 == 0])` that will return a list with the values that you want.

Comment: What do you mean with `reverse`? I cannot really see where you reversed something in your example. It looks more like sorting the list, and splitting in before into a even and an odd list.

Comment: I'd  like to solve this question by using the linked list but not list...anyway, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question isn't 100% clear: are you trying to split the linked list in half, with odd integers in the beginning and even ones at the end?  Are you trying to partition the list without respect to the values themselves?

Additionally, there must be code that you haven't submitted along with your question...I've taken my best guess as to what that code might look like.

The snippet below returns your desired output:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
        self.next_node = None

class Linkedlist:
    def __init__(self, L=None):
        self.head = Node(L[0])
        current = self.head
        for value in L[1:]:
            current.next_node = Node(value)
            current = current.next_node

    def partlyreverse(self):
        tail_start = self.head
        tail_end = self.head
        tail2_start = None
        tail2_end = None

        current_node = self.head.next_node

        while current_node != None:
            if current_node.value % 2 == 1:
                next_current_node = current_node.next_node
                current_node.next_node = tail_start
                tail_start = current_node
                current_node = next_current_node
            else:
                if not tail2_start:
                    tail2_start = current_node
                    tail2_end = tail2_start
                    current_node = current_node.next_node             
                else:
                    tail2_end.next_node = current_node
                    tail2_end = current_node
                    current_node = current_node.next_node 

        tail_end.next_node = tail2_start
        self.head = tail_start

L = Linkedlist([7,5,3,1,2,4,6,8])

L.partlyreverse()

def RecursivelyPrintNodes(node):
    if node != None:
        print node.value
        RecursivelyPrintNodes(node.next_node)

RecursivelyPrintNodes(L.head)

# 1,3,5,7,2,4,6,8
```

Finally, I see what you're going for in your code, but just as a note, your code as written won't compile (there are indentation errors within your class).

Comment: Great; my pleasure! :) Don't forget to "Accept" the answer, too - that way other SO folks will know your problem was solved @qiancheng

Answer (score 0):

You basically need to check the starting of your list holds odd or even number! And based on that you need to reverse!

```
>>> s
(7, 3, 5, 1, 2, 4, 6, 8)
>>> sorted(filter(lambda x:(x%2!=0 and s[0]%2!=0) or (x%2==0 and s[0]%2==0),s)) + sorted(filter(lambda x:(x%2!=0 and s[-1]%2!=0) or (x%2==0 and s[-1]%2==0),s))
[1, 3, 5, 7, 2, 4, 6, 8]
```

Comment: well,I tried it but LinkedList object has no attribute 'sorted',I want to reconnect the node in linkedlist not convert it into list...